# Is it possible to edit and save a form as a new record, while also keeping the old entry as a separate record in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

For example, I have a form for info associated with version 4.1. What I want to do is edit that info and save it as version 4.2, but also keep the previous version. Obviously I could do this by creating a new record, but a lot of the info remains the same which is why I want to avoid that. Right now if I edit the info on the form it just overwrites the old info.

Comment: Your question has a lot of language/terminology issues but assuming your question is: Can I have a form automatically create a duplicate of the current record and set it as the current record so I neither overwrite the previous record not have to re-enter all the information, then the answer is yes, you can write code in Access that does that.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Use the function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42697353/msaccess-requery-a-subform-after-insert/42697864#42697864) as basis to duplicate the record.

Add a field to the table named, say, Archived, and perhaps also a date field for the archive date. Then, before updating, copy the record and update Archived and the date field in the source record.